# jQuery hover repositions on subsequent hovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, position

I have a `hover` event set on an element that use's jQuery UI's `position` function to show a `div` right underneath it, with the "out" set to hide that `div`.

The problem is, subsequent hovers position that `div` further and further on each hover.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Shpigford/8ZkgJ/

Hover over the red box, then hover over it again and you'll see the blue box quickly get positioned further and further to the right.

Same thing happens if I change to a `click` event. Seems like something odd is happening with positioning when I hide the `div` and then try to show it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `position({...}).show()`, use `show().position({...})`. The reason is that `positon` won't work when the element is invisible. You can find the following note at http://api.jqueryui.com/position/:

> jQuery UI does not support positioning hidden elements

Comment: oh Right man Perfect answer !  Sorry for posting similar kind of answer, i did'n see your answer because of writing answer window..  removed my answer and also +1 for nice answer